# Smooth Movement with pygame states

Tags: python, pygame, state

I'm currently working on a project, which basically is creating the pokemon game with pygame. To do so, I adapted an online code that consisted on game states (https://python-forum.io/Thread-PyGame-Creating-a-state-machine) I created a game state where the user will move the sprite with <kbd>w</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> keys, the problem is that, although it does detect the key pressed and moves the sprite, it doesn't detect when the key is being held and moves only 5 pixels the sprite(id does not continue to move, it gets stuck).
I tried moving the sprite movement code into the control class but I had the same problem, I think that it could be because the loop in which it's located interrupts the movement. I'd really appreciate the help here.
Here´s the Control Class code:

```py
From player import * 
import pygame as pg
bg = pygame.image.load("imgs/bg_prueba.jpg")
class Control:
    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.fps = 60
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode(bg.get_rect().size)
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

        """ CREATE TRAINER """
        motor = Motor()
        self.trainer = player(40, 40, motor.pokedex(), self.screen)

    def setup_states(self, state_dict, start_state):
        self.state_dict = state_dict
        self.state_name = start_state
        self.state = self.state_dict[self.state_name]

    def flip_state(self):
        self.state.done = False
        previous, self.state_name = self.state_name, self.state.next
        self.state.cleanup()
        self.state = self.state_dict[self.state_name]
        self.state.startup()
        self.state.previous = previous

    def update(self, dt):
        if self.state.quit:
            self.done = True
        elif self.state.done:
            self.flip_state()
        self.state.update(self.screen, dt)

    def event_loop(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            self.state.get_event(event)

    def main_game_loop(self):
        while not self.done:
            delta_time = self.clock.tick(self.fps) / 1000.0
            self.event_loop()
            self.update(delta_time)
            pg.display.update()
```

And this is the Game State code:

```py
from States import *
from Gym import *
from Control import *
gyms = [Gym(pygame.image.load("imgs/gym1.png"), 150,5)]
bg = pygame.image.load("imgs/bg_prueba.jpg")
class Map(States):
    def __init__(self):
        States.__init__(self)
        self.next = 'menu'

    def cleanup(self):
        print('cleaning up Game state stuff')

    def startup(self):
        print('starting Game state stuff')

    def get_event(self, event):
        clock.tick(20)
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                self.trainer.x -= self.trainer.v
                self.trainer.right = False
                self.trainer.left = True
                self.trainer.down = False
                self.trainer.up = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                self.trainer.x += self.trainer.v
                self.trainer.right = True
                self.trainer.left = False
                self.trainer.down = False
                self.trainer.up = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                self.trainer.y -= self.trainer.v
                self.trainer.right = False
                self.trainer.left = False
                self.trainer.down = False
                self.trainer.up = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                self.trainer.y += self.trainer.v
                self.trainer.right = False
                self.trainer.left = False
                self.trainer.down = True
                self.trainer.up = False

    def update(self, screen, dt):
        global walkCount
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        self.trainer.draw()
        gyms[0].draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
```

And the Trainer code for any possible doubts

```py
from Motor import *
walkDown = [pygame.image.load("imgs/run_down1.png"), pygame.image.load("imgs/run_down2.png")]
walkUp = [pygame.image.load("imgs/run_up1.png"), pygame.image.load("imgs/run_up2.png")]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load("imgs/run_left1.png"), pygame.image.load("imgs/run_left2.png")]
walkRight = [pygame.image.load("imgs/run_right1.png"), pygame.image.load("imgs/run_right2.png")]
stand = pygame.image.load("imgs/stand.png")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, pokedex, screen):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pokedex = pokedex
        self.right = False
        self.left = False
        self.up = False
        self.down = False
        self.v = 5
        self.width, self.height = stand.get_size()
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.x2 = x + self.width
        self.y2 = y + self.height
        self.screen = screen
    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(stand, (self.x, self.y))
        if self.left:
            self.screen.blit(walkLeft[0], (self.x, self.y))
            self.screen.blit(walkLeft[1], (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.right:
            self.screen.blit(walkRight[0], (self.x, self.y))
            self.screen.blit(walkRight[1], (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.up:
            self.screen.blit(walkUp[0], (self.x, self.y))
            self.screen.blit(walkUp[1], (self.x, self.y))
        elif self.down:
            self.screen.blit(walkDown[0], (self.x, self.y))
            self.screen.blit(walkDown[1], (self.x, self.y))
        else:
            self.screen.blit(stand, (self.x, self.y))
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 0, 0), self.rect, 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KEYDOWN` and `KEYUP` event occur only once when a key is pressed. I recommend to gent the current sates of the keys by `pygame.key.get_pressed()`, to achieve a continuously smooth movement. e.g:

```py
class Control:
    # [...]

    def event_loop(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.done = True
            self.state.get_event(event)
        self.state.get_keys()
```

```py
class Control:
    # [...]

    def get_event(self, event):
        clock.tick(20)

    def get_keys(self):
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.trainer.x -= self.trainer.v
        elif keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.trainer.x += self.trainer.v
        elif keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
            self.trainer.y -= self.trainer.v
        elif keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
            self.trainer.y += self.trainer.v
```